# How to concatenate an optional array to another array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I know this sounds ridiculous but I am seriously confused now.
Basically I have two vars, one is `[Data]` and one is `Array<Data>?`

I need to combine these two.
I've tried do `var1+var2`, which is giving me errors say can't do binary operations on these two. 
So I googled, I can use append method, now there comes more questions:

1. the append method is crossed out in autofill, so I am not sure if I should use it.
2. Even if I try to use it (while it's being crossed out), it is still giving me errors

Here is the code and errors I get:

```
var a1:[Data] //a return value from other function
var a2:Array<Data>? //a parameter that's passed in

a1.append(contentsOf:a2) //Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value
a1+a2 //Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Array<Data>' and 'Array<Data>?'
```

Both arrays can be empty, how can I concatenate these two arrays?

Comment: if one of them is optional, you can for example `var1 + (var2 ?? [])` By the way `[Data]` and `Array<Data>` is literally the same thing. The `?` makes the difference.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you that's it, solved it!

Comment: @Sulthan you should post your comment as an answer. The optional think is the answer.

Comment: Do not edit answers into the question. Either wait for @Sulthan to post his comment as an answer, or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the arrays is optional. You have to handle the possible `nil` value somehow.

A simple solution using nil-coalescing:

```
let concatenated = var1 + (var2 ?? [])
```

or, slightly more complex:

```
var concatenated = var1

if let var2 = var2 {
   concatenated.append(var2)
}
```

There are other possible solutions, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Sulthan's answer is the quick solution, but if you do this a lot in your code, you can overload `+` to handle it for you automatically:

```
extension Array {
    static func + (lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]?) -> [Element] {
        return lhs + (rhs ?? [])
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if the optional would be on the left side of the operand? Addition should be commutative. But would it make sense to add something to a `nil` array?

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend RangeReplaceable Collection and implement a custom append method as well as addition and mutating addition operators as follow:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    public mutating func append<S: Sequence>(contentsOf sequence: S?) where Element == S.Element {
        guard let sequence = sequence else { return }
        reserveCapacity(count + sequence.underestimatedCount)
        append(contentsOf: sequence)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    public static func += <S: Sequence>(lhs: inout Self, rhs: S?) where Element == S.Element {
        guard let rhs = rhs else { return }
        lhs.reserveCapacity(lhs.count + rhs.underestimatedCount)
        lhs.append(contentsOf: rhs)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    public static func + <S: Sequence>(lhs: Self, rhs: S?) -> Self where Element == S.Element {
        guard let rhs = rhs else { return lhs }
        var result = Self()
        result.reserveCapacity(lhs.count + rhs.underestimatedCount)
        result.append(contentsOf: lhs)
        result.append(contentsOf: rhs)
        return result
    }
}
```

---

Playground Testing

```
var a1 = "abc"
let a2: String? = "d"
let a3: String? = nil
let a4: [Character]? = ["e","f"]

a1 + a2 + a3 + a4  // "abcdef"

a1 + a2
print("a1:", a1)
a1 += a2
print("a1:", a1)
a1 + a3
print("a1:", a1)
a1 += a3
print("a1:", a1)
a1 + a4
print("a1:", a1)
a1 += a4
print("a1:", a1)

a1.append(contentsOf: ["e","f","g"])
print("a1:", a1)
a1.append(contentsOf: "hijkl")
print("a1:", a1)
```